# JSON_DECODE() with malformed character

Tags: php, json

I am receiving back an ASCII string (created by a C program) that is JSON formatted. The problem is that PHP is getting a 5 error on decoding it (malformed UTF-8). In the string is a 215 character. Substring:

```
1280ï544
```

How do I deal with this so that I don't get the decoding error? (I want to filter out/hide ALL such characters, not just the one instance).

I sort of feel like I should know this but I've been coding for 20 straight hours and need some help.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII does not contain characters like ï, extended ASCII does. The PHP manual states:

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

So that means that you must convert the string to UTF-8. It is likely that your current string is in ISO-8859-1, in which case you can convert your string to UTF-8 using [utf8-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) before you run it through json_decode.

Comment: When I do that I get a syntax error. Code sequence in test program is: $r=utf8_encode($results); $a=json_decode($r,1); This returns error #4

Comment: Syntax of the JSON? Then your original input may be another charset.

Comment: I've run the JSON through json lint and it validates. The problem is that PHP is treating the string as a problem. I'm sure it has to do with encoding, just not sure of what I need to do when I get the string back from the server. Do I encode it, decode it or decode/encode it. The two things I know are that the string is straight ASCII and that it is proper JSON format. The data was sourced for the return to me from a MySQL field (UTF-8).